# Facebook API for iOS - external mobile app browser

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, cordova, ios7

I'm using Facebook Cordova plugin for my mobile app project. My problem is, how to open web link on mobile app browser, not Facebook in app browser that user already posted on Facebook? Below is my code for Facebook wall post sharing. It happened on iOS7, not iOS6.

```
function facebookWallPost() {
    var params = {
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'Buzz Feed',
        link: sessionStorage.targetLink ,
        picture: sessionStorage.imageLink,
        caption: sessionStorage.description,
        description: 'Grab this item. Click to buy.'
    };
    console.log(params);
    FB.ui(params, function(obj) {
        console.log(obj);
    });
}
```

What I want:

[image]

I don't want like this one:

[image]

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ready found the answer. Using cordova inappbrowser plugin.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser